# Plotting a perpendicular line to a tangent

Tags: python-3.x, function, matplotlib

What is wrong at the end of the code called # Perpendicular line that the green line is not perpendicular to the orange tangent, please?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as patches
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,3))
x_start = -2
x_end = 32
x = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, 1000)

def f(x):
   a = 1
   mu1 = 5 
   mu2 = 25
   sigma = 2.5
   y1 = a*np.exp(-(x-mu1)**2/(2*sigma**2))
   y2 = a*np.exp(-(x-mu2)**2/(2*sigma**2))
   return y1+y2
y=f(x)

def deriv(f,x):
    h = 0.000000001                 # step-size 
    return (f(x+h) - f(x))/h        # definition of derivative

def tangent_line(f, x_0, a, b):
    x = np.linspace(a, b, 1000)
    y = f(x) 
    y_0 = f(x_0)
    y_tan = deriv(f,x_0) * (x - x_0) + y_0 
    P = (x_0, y_0)
    return y_tan

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlim(15, x_end)
plt.ylim(-0.05, 1.8)

# Chose a point and plot a tangent
C = 270
l = 30 
y_tan = tangent_line(f,x[-C],-2,32)
cor = 0.02

# Tangent
plt.plot(x[-C-l:-C+l], y_tan[-C-l:-C+l])  

# Perpendicular line
P1 = (x[-C-l:-C+l][0], y_tan[-C-l:-C+l][0])
ax.scatter(x[-C-l:-C+l][0], y_tan[-C-l:-C+l][0])
b = (x[-C], y[-C])
ax.scatter(x[-C], y[-C])
u = [b[0] - P1[0], b[1] - P1[0]]
plt.scatter(b[0] - P1[0], b[1] - P1[1]) 
u_per = (u[1], u[0])
shorten = 0.45
P_per = (b[0] + shorten * u_per[0], b[1] + shorten * u_per[1])
plt.scatter(b[0] + shorten * u_per[0], b[1] + shorten * u_per[1])
plt.plot([b[0], P_per[0]], [b[1], P_per[1]])
plt.show()
```

The desired result is the right angle between the green line and the orange tangent line. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just because the chart is stretched out horizontally. Set for example `figsize=(5,5)` and everything looks fine (almost fine to be precise, the actual axes aspect ratio is `0.9935` instead of `1.0` because the y tick labels are a bit wider than the height of the x tick labels):
[image]

If you want to get a precise and universal result independently of actual figure size (so that you can keep it for instance `(10,3)` or can interactively change it) then set the [aspect ratio of the axes](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect) to `1` by adding at the end of your script:

```
ax.set_box_aspect(1)
```

[image]